# Accessing data outside of a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using fetch and a promise to make 2 calls to api's and return the data. I have no problem getting the data within the promise I just can't access it outside of it. I would have thought `return apiData` would return it for use? I imagine I'm missing something like a `.finalise` or `.success` to return it outside the promise?

Essentially I'm trying to figure out how I can access the JSON object outside the promise which includes all the data, not just the JSON structure.

```
var api1 = fetch('api.example1.com/search').then(function(response){ 
         return response.json()
});
var api2 = fetch('api.example2.com/search').then(function(response){
         return response.json()
});

var apiData = {"api1":{},"api2":{}};
Promise.all([api1,api2]).then(function(values){
    apiData.api1 = values[0];
    apiData.api2 = values[1];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(apiData, null, 4)); 
    //this displays all the data as it's still within the promise
    return apiData;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(apiData, null, 4)); 
    //this doesn't get the values of the api1 and api2 data as it's outside of the
    //promise and only displays the object structure
```

Comment: Promises don't magically make asynchronous functions synchronous - they just make them easier to interact with. Put all the code that depends on `apiData` being populated inside of the `Promise.all` `then`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance :) I'm only just learning about them. But putting those fetch calls inside won't make it function?

Comment: your code functions perfectly well, your only mistake is accessing the result of an asynchronous call synchronously - i.e. the last line is the only error in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you, that was the perfect hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always access `apiData` globally. Just make sure you access it after data is assigned. The reason you don't get the data because you call `console.log` before the promise return.

Try this:

```
var apiData = {"api1":{},"api2":{}};
Promise.all([api1,api2]).then(function(values){
        apiData.api1 = values[0];
        apiData.api2 = values[1];
        console.log(JSON.stringify(apiData, null, 4)); 
        //this displays all the data as it's still within the promise
        return apiData;
    })
    .then(function(){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(apiData, null, 4)); // You still reference apiData globally
            //this doesn't get the values of the api1 and api2 data as it's outside of the
            //promise and only displays the object structure
    });
```

Or even this (only for demonstration, don't use it):

```
var apiData = {"api1":{},"api2":{}};
Promise.all([api1,api2]).then(function(values){
    apiData.api1 = values[0];
    apiData.api2 = values[1];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(apiData, null, 4)); 
    //this displays all the data as it's still within the promise
    return apiData;
});
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(apiData, null, 4)); // should be now able to log the data here 
        //this doesn't get the values of the api1 and api2 data as it's outside of the
        //promise and only displays the object structure
}, 1000); // assume the fetch calls finish in 1s
```

Comment: oooh, don't even suggest the `setTimeout` *hack* - it should never be needed for properly written code

Comment: @wdetac Thanks wdetac, a very silly mistake on my behalf. Your explanation was perfect and it's now returning after the promise return.